# Get unique pairs of row names and column names based on data table entries

Tags: r, data.table

Here is my data table:

```
    A    B    C
A   1   0.8  0.2
B  0.8   1   0.3
C  0.2  0.3   1
```

I am trying to get the unique pairs of row names and column names based on the entries. For example, if I am looking at `> 0.5`, my output would be:

```
A B 0.8
```

If I am looking at `< 0.5`, my output would be:

```
B C 0.3
A C 0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical `melt` situation (though it needs some seasoning with upper or lower.tri)

```r
dat <- read.table(text=
"    A    B    C
A   1   0.8  0.2
B  0.8   1   0.3
C  0.2  0.3   1
", header=TRUE )
dat[ !upper.tri(dat) ] <- NA

dat <- as.data.frame( dat )
dat <- tibble::rownames_to_column( dat, "V1" )
setDT(dat)

use.this <- melt( dat, id.vars="V1", variable.name="V2" )[ !is.na(value) ]

use.this[ value < .5 ]

use.this[ value > 0.5 ]
```

It looks like this:

```
> use.this[ value < .5 ]
   V1 V2 value
1:  A  C   0.2
2:  B  C   0.3

> use.this[ value > .5 ]
   V1 V2 value
1:  A  B   0.8
```

Comment: `dat <- tibble::rownames_to_column( dat, "V1" )` is not working for me, I get: `is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE`

Comment: Ah. dat needs to be a data.frame, I added `dat <- as.data.frame( dat )` up there in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, using `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get the row and column numbers that meet the condition.

```
df[lower.tri(df, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
mat <- which(df < 0.5, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(rowname = rownames(df)[mat[, 1]], 
           colname = colnames(df)[mat[, 2]], 
           value = df[mat])

#  rowname colname value
#1       A       C   0.2
#2       B       C   0.3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1, 0.8, 0.2), B = c(0.8, 1, 0.3), C = c(0.2, 
0.3, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
M <- matrix(c(1,0.8,0.2,0.8,1,0.3,0.2,0.3,1), nrow=3L, 
    dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3]))

allDT <- data.table(rn=rep(rownames(M), nrow(M)), 
    cn=rep(colnames(M), each=ncol(M)), 
    val=as.vector(M))
DT <- unique(allDT[, .(val=val), .(rn=pmin(rn, cn), cn=pmax(rn, cn))])
DT[val<0.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been tagged [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). So, here is a simple solution which uses only [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax. In addition, it suggests lookup functions (**EDIT:** in 3 different flavours) which require less keystrokes.

```
library(data.table)
wide <- fread("    A    B    C
A   1   0.8  0.2
B  0.8   1   0.3
C  0.2  0.3   1")
long <- melt(wide, id.var = "V1", variable.name = "V2", 
             variable.factor = FALSE)[V1 < V2]

long
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  B   0.8
> 2:  A  C   0.2
> 3:  B  C   0.3
> ```

Note that the upper triangular part of `wide` is picked *after reshaping to long format* by subsetting `[V1 < V2]` which ensures that only unique pairs are considered.

`long` can be queried by subsetting, e.g.,

```
long[value < 0.5]
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  C   0.2
> 2:  B  C   0.3
> ```

```
long[value > 0.5]
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  B   0.8
> ```

#### lookup function

`long` can be queried by defining a lookup function:

```
l <- function(cond) eval(parse(text = paste0("long[value", cond, "]")))
```

which can be called, e.g.,

```
l("< .5")
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  C   0.2
> 2:  B  C   0.3
> ```

```
l("> .5")
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  B   0.8
> ```

```
l("== .3")
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  B  C   0.3
> ```

#### EDIT: lookup function with 2 arguments

Alternatively, the lookup function can be defined to allow for 2 arguments, one for the comparision operator, one for the numerical values:

```
l2 <- function(op, v) long[do.call(op, list(value, v))]

l2("%between%", c(0.25, 0.95))
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  B   0.8
> 2:  B  C   0.3
> ```

---

Or, with the new interface for *programming on data.table* (available with `data.table` development version 1.14.1):

```
l3 <- function(op, v) long[op(value, v), env = list(op = as.name(op), v = v)]

l3("%in%", c(0.2, 0.3))
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 value
> 1:  A  C   0.2
> 2:  B  C   0.3
> ```